# How to change button background color, on click, infinitely in javascript or css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have created a button that changes the background color to gradient and when I double click it, it returns back. When I click the button, it changes the color and text(hello) of itself to gradient and text(hi), but when I double click it, the button doesn't return back, it just shows the gradient and text(hi). I tried the codes answered to the question 'toggle button background color when clicked' they are also not working. Can you help me to solve this problem?

I tried some javascript code, that I found in stack overflow. But it is not working.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.body.style.background = "linear-gradient(orange, white, green)";
}

function myFunction2() {
  document.body.style.background = "#22232e";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()" ondblclick="myFunction2()">
<span>hello</span>
<span>hi</span>
</button>
```

Comment: You need to ask a good question. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, specially the "Help others reproduce the problem" part. With what you are telling, we can't answer anything because we don't know what code you have or what have you tried... we can just search Google for you and link you to a couple more answers, which they will be the same you already found if you searched properly.

Comment: Like this one [Toggle button background color when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65350502/toggle-button-background-color-when-clicked)

Comment: I've converted the code you provided to a snippet so it can be run here.  It works fine as far as I can tell.   Perhaps you are not double-clicking quick enough.  Perhaps you have some other code interfering (eg if you move the button).  Perhaps you are using something other than a web browser on a PC and double-click works differently on that environment.  See https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this using css [transition](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) property.If you want it change it's background color countinuously then you can try [keyframes](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.php) animation.And for click event you can use ':focus' pseudo-class.For example------
css property

```
#button{
   background-color: red;

   transition: background-color 2s linear;
}

#button:focus{

background-color: purple;

}
```

Or you can use keyframes animation.It will change background color infinite loop after click on the button. For example---

```
#I{
            background-color: black;
            transition: background-color 2s linear ;
            color: wheat;
}

@keyframes colors {
            from{
                background-color: red;
            }
            to{
                background-color: purple;
            }
}
#I:focus{
            animation: colors 2s linear infinite alternate;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**The HTML:**

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" ondblclick="myFunction2()">
    <span class="hello"> hello </span>
    <span  class="hii" style="display:none;"> hii </span>
</button>
```

**The JavaScript:**

```
function myFunction () {
     document.body.style.backgroundColor ="grey";
     document.querySelector('.hello').style.display ="none";
     document.querySelector('.hii').style.display ="inline-block";
  }
  
  function myFunction2 () {
     document.body.style.background ="initial";
     document.querySelector('.hello').style.display ="inline-block";
     document.querySelector('.hii').style.display ="none";
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).